# Display the first few lines of a file

Tags: command-line

I have a folder with quite a few files in it.  I want to display the following:

```
filename_1
first line of file1
second line of file1
third line of file1
filename_2
first line of file2
second line of file2
third line of file2
filename_3
first line of file3
second line of file3
third line of file3
```

etc.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You use the `head` command to do this, with the -n argument with the number of lines from each file, like this:

```
head -n3 *
```

or

```
head -n3 *.txt
```

This also works for a single file:

```
head -n3 filename.txt
```

Comment: Just as a comment (I DO like the cleanness of the proposed solution), this command won't write out filenames, but just the first lines of the files

Comment: @luri - Really? In Ubuntu `head` version `head (GNU coreutils) 8.5` it by default will. Or maybe you're using an alias `head --quiet`?

Comment: @luri: It did output the filenames for me as well.

Comment: Damn yes... it was aliased (--silent, actually, instead of --quiet) and I don't know why. Two answers in one for arrange ;)

Comment: but if i want only couple of bytes, not lines of file ? i got big json file head dod not help (

Answer (score 14):

**head**

You use `head` with the `-n` option.

`head -n 10 FILE`

This will print the first ten lines of a file.

Another useful variation would be `-n -NUMBER`.

`head -n -10 FILE`

This will print all but the last ten lines of a file.

To solve your problem and get your desired output you can do the following.

```
basename * && head -n NUMBER *
```

or

```
basename *.FILETYPE && head -n NUMBER *.FILETYPE
```

This will get you following output:

```
FILENAME
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
LINE THREE
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want, hopefuly:

```
find . -print -exec head {} -n 3 \;
```

`-print` will show the filename and the rest (from -`exec`) will show the first 3 lines of each file

Change the number according to your needs...

Answer (score 1):

To add the filename to the head output use 'head -v'. So 'head -vn 3 *.html' gives me:

```
# head -vn 3 *.html
==> WebInfo.html <==
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

==> convert.html <==
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

==> misc.html <==
<html>
<head>
<title>WIP</title>
```